# joomla directory permission problem

Tags: linux, permissions, joomla

I have installed joomla on my new account . All the files are showing the FTP username as the owner of files . But when i go to joomla admin section and check directory permissions , it says the few folders are unwritable .

Does it mean that admin page is using different user than FTP username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not about ownership, usually its about permissions. If you want to understand it all - there is a quite extensive FAQ

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=121470

Short one - look into the the test results - note the files and directories to be changed. Depending on the security configuration of your Web server the recommended default permissions is:
    755 for directories
    644 for files

change them. For Filezilla (a free ftp client - my best guess on what you are using) a good tutrial how change file permissions is :

http://www.codeunit.co.za/2008/07/18/remotely-changing-multiple-linux-file-permissions-with-filezilla/

Since the owner usually has the most rights, changing the ownership of all files to the http-server process owner could also work' but then again - you would have to do this each time and its not possible via ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if this is hosted on apache, the apache server usually runs as user `www-data`.